# Как отображать нормальные данные в таблице а не из коды

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio

У меня появилась проблема с отображение в Visual Studio, Windows Form Всё по стандарту я подключаю БД Осуществляю её просмотр с помощью компонента DataGridView ну и её заполнение, но я не знаю как избавиться от отображение в таблице кодов[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Условно я хочу что бы вместо Код_Вида_Нарушений отображался сам вид нарушения
Можно ли это осуществить с помощью SQL запроса ?

Comment: Не создавайте дубликаты. Отредактируйте уже существующий вопрос.